# Drupal 8 hook_field_views_data error Undefined index: table

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-8

I'm coding a custom module with view relationship support to custom table.

I have succesful added the relationship via the `hook_field_views_data` in `moduleName.view.inc`

```
function easyme_field_views_data(FieldStorageConfigInterface $field_storage) {
  $data = views_field_default_views_data($field_storage);
  foreach ($data as $table_name => $table_data) {
    $data[$table_name][$field_storage->getName() . '_value']['relationship'] = [
      'group'      => 'EasyMe',
      'id'         => 'standard',
      'base'       => 'easyme_event',
      'base field' => 'event_id',
      'label'      => t('EasyMe event from @field_name', ['@field_name' => $field_storage->getName()]),
    ];
  }
}
```

When I try it in a view and save I get this error:

> ```
> Notice: Undefined index: table in Drupal\views\Plugin\views\relationship\RelationshipPluginBase->calculateDependencies()
> ```

Anybody have a solution for that?

And in the same module I also add filters to view in `moduleName.module`

```
function easyme_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['views']['easysme_event_start_date'] = [
    'title'  => t('EasyMe event start date'),
    'help'   => t('Filter the view by EasyMe event start date.'),
    'filter' => [
      'group' => 'EasyMe',
      'id'    => 'easyme_start_date_filter',
    ],
  ];
  $data['views']['easysme_event_end_date']   = [
    'title'  => t('EasyMe event end date'),
    'help'   => t('Filter the view by EasyMe event end date.'),
    'filter' => [
      'group' => 'EasyMe',
      'id'    => 'easyme_end_date_filter',
    ],
  ];
}
```

How can I make sure the filters only are shown if the above relationship has been added?

Thanks in advance.